NoSuchMethodException on Android P on Facebook Conceal Library
NoSuchMethodException occurs when using Facebook Conceal library on Android P device.
The exception is thrown when calling init method of SoLoader class:
SoLoader.init(this, false);

Error Stacktrace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: nativeLoad [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.ClassLoader, class java.lang.String]
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.getNativeLoadRuntimeMethod(SoLoader.java:297)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.initSoLoader(SoLoader.java:249)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.initImpl(SoLoader.java:156)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:131)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:115)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:142)

There is an open issue in the repository of the library: https://github.com/facebookarchive/conceal/issues/197

The problem relates to a Soloader dependency, which is part of the Conceal library. To resolve the issue, you need to remove the Soloader dependency from the Conceal library, apply this fix to 0.4.1 version of the Soloader, build the aar out of it and add it as a separate, independent dependency. You cannot use higher versions of the Soloader, because they are not compatible with the Conceal library.

Updated aar file of Conceal is available under this link.
Updated aar file of Soloader is available under this link.

You need to store the aar file in the Android project's /libs folder and build.gradle file should contain the below:
implementation(name: 'com.facebook.conceal-2.0.2-edited', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'com.facebook.soloader-0.4.1.1', ext: 'aar')

Steps to remove Soloader dependency from the Conceal:

Download the AAR file of the Conceal library from Maven Central.

Extract the content of the AAR file. You can use any ZIP extraction tool for this:
unzip conceal-2.0.2.aar -d conceal_extracted

Remove all Soloader files:
zip -d conceal_extracted/classes.jar "com/facebook/soloader/"*

Repackage the modified AAR file:
jar cvf com.facebook.conceal-2.0.2-edited.aar -C conceal_extracted .



Instead of manually modifying the aar file just forking the Github repo, correcting the dependency and then use it via Jitpack.io should be an alternative. And others having the same problem could then also use your repo.

@Robert, That was my initial attempt, but I couldn't succeed there. Therefore posted only this manual process.
